# how to import a mathematical equation in Corel Draw X5

Tags: text, pdf, corel-draw, jpg

I have a problem I could not solve. I am doing a poster in Corel Draw X5, and as it is a physics poster, I need to put mathematical equations in it. The Corel built in text editor is just completely not enough for that, and as far as I tried I couldnt' find any way to transport (graphically!) a mathematical equation created in word 2007, into Corel Draw, other than making a JPEG file of it!

And to do that, I need to do a full zoom of a pdf file created from the word file, and then do print screen many times, and put them together, to at last have my equation in 4000x300 pixels resolution. Lower resolution and it's REALLY poor quality, because it's all in length, so characters are small! Even acrobat pro cannot do me a 1200dpi jpeg file when saving as jpeg, it's even worse than print screen!

A clean solution would be to use postscript or EPS...but I couldn't make Corel accept ANY .ps or EPS file I gave it to import! Nothing at all! Always errors...if anyone has a way to at least make corel accept ONE .ps file completely without errors, even with a simple "Hello world" inside, it would be great! A mess with fonts or something as always, and even when the pdf page contains only Times New Roman, at the opening of the .PS file in Corel, Corel will see some Helvetica somewhere, say that it tries to replace it with another font, but the final output is just blank, everytime! Or sometimes instead of the text I was waiting, there will be some warning about a PPD file incorrect or printer not supporting postscript level 3, or something...and the text of the warning will indeed be converted to curves! I'm just lost here...

So for now I will just take a lot of time to obtain High res JPG versions of my equations...by putting together several screenshots...because no matter how much you zoom in adobe reader, the equation is perfect, it IS postscript inside, GSVIEW can see it, but Corel just refuses everything!

Thank you very much, you would really help me on this!

Answer (score 3):

1. Export equation from word to pdf **File – Save as – Pdf**
2. Indesign, Create new document, place pdf **File – Place** (cmd+D)
3. Export .eps, **File – Export – eps**
4. Place .eps to corel (i'm cheked in illustrator - equation in vector)

Microsoft word
[image]

Adobe illustrator
[image]

Comment: you can place a PDF file in Corel Draw also

Comment: I do not have indesign right now, but if I get it I will test it. Thanks for the answer! However I am interesting in this "outlining" procedure that goes by preprinting...

Answer (score 2):

**@sergeydyadyul** has it right for the most part. Let me tell you a little background on your problems. The equations that you create in MS Word are using symbols that are part of the Cambria Math typeface. When you attempt to create an EPS or PS file to import into Corel, it is not embedding the font into the document. So when you try to import the document into Corel it doesn't know which font it should be using to display the equation symbols.

You will need to outline your fonts (convert them to paths) before you can import the equation into Corel. The problem is how do you outline your fonts? If you know any print providers, they will have prepress tools that can convert the fonts inside PDFs to outlines.

Comment: Hello, you are right in that, it was probably the font. I do not know exactly what is outlining but I see what you mean: making EPS understanding the text as curves, not as letters, just as it does when converting a logo to EPS for example.

Comment: EPS includes font information --- the problem is that CorelDRAW doesn't have support for Cambria's math typesetting.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is quite old, I believe that this answer might help others with the same or a similar problem.

### Using "integrated" LaTeX for typesetting

As @KingOliver already mentioned, using LaTeX is a good way for typesetting mathematical formula and equations.
A better solution, than dowloading GIFs without any option to change the equations after inserting, might be to "integrate" LaTeX using VBA.

Jan Bender has done some work in VBA and is offering his CorelDRAW "add-in" for free.

The add-in will allow you to insert objects, typeset by LaTeX, into your CorelDRAW file as a group of curve objects. These curves can be formatted like any other in CorelDRAW. And last but not least, it is possible to change the formula after inserting, since its LaTeX-code is stored as object data variable.

### Download

Get the VBA files by Jan Bender from [impulse-based.de](http://www.impulse-based.de/index.php/downloads)

### Requirements

- CorelDRAW running on a 32bit or 64bit host
- [Some basic knowledge of LaTeX math-mode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)
- `latex.exe` and `dvips.exe` to be in the windows `path`-variable (Installing any LaTeX-Distribution, for example [MikTeX](http://www.miktex.org) or [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), should put them there)

### Installation and Troubleshooting

Instruction on how to install it, combined with some troubleshooting, can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80268).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you are passingly fluent in LaTeX, a mathematical typesetter, you can use [this link](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and download the GIF that is your equation. It cuts it out for you as well.

Comment: This site lets the user to input as symbols and to output the result as typesetting or webpage design description language. It should be cosidered as a programming text editor with symbolic input. The downloadable bitmap file is good enough  for onscreen only. Download in vector format gives a part of the result as fonts,. To be usable, it should have only curves. EMF outbut , besides the need  to have math fonts, was quite jagged.