# How to type complex Mathematical equations/fractions in Corel Draw

Tags: corel-draw, mathematics

I am working on Maths exam papers for an educational institute, I mostly do all my print related work on Corel Draw, I was thinking if there is any way of writing complex Mathematical Equation in Corel Draw X6 easily.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8279/how-to-import-a-mathematical-equation-in-corel-draw-x5/55748#55748

Answer (score 1):

For writing complex math equations in CorelDRAW I would suggest the folllowing:

### Using "integrated" LaTeX for typesetting

Using LaTeX is a good way for typesetting mathematical formula and equations.
A good solution to use with CorelDRAW might be to "integrate" LaTeX using VBA.

Jan Bender has done some work in VBA and is offering his CorelDRAW "add-in" for free.

The add-in will allow you to insert objects, typeset by LaTeX, into your CorelDRAW file as a group of curve objects. These curves can be formatted like any other in CorelDRAW. And last but not least, it is possible to change the formula after inserting, since its LaTeX-code is stored as object data variable.

### Download

Get the VBA files by Jan Bender from [impulse-based.de](http://www.impulse-based.de/index.php/downloads) (*Latex for CorelDraw*).

### Requirements

- CorelDRAW running on a 32bit or 64bit host
- [Some basic knowledge of LaTeX math-mode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)
- `latex.exe` and `dvips.exe` to be in the windows `path`-variable (Installing any LaTeX-Distribution, for example [MikTeX](http://www.miktex.org) or [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), should put them there)

### Installation and Troubleshooting

Instruction on how to install it, combined with some troubleshooting, can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80268).

---

**Note:** As this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/8279/45973) is quite similar, the same answer can be found [there](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/55748/45973) as well. No I'm not plagiarizing myself... ;) It's stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions), that it's not acceptable to post the same answer on different questions. So, if requested, I would vote to delete my answer on the other question - since it's rather about importing `*.ps`/`*.eps` files to CorelDRAW, than on writing math *in* CorelDRAW (If it is a question at all, since there is no question mark in it). Although I believe, that this answer is helpful on both questions, even if the are not duplicates.